# Get same character for integer value in python like in VB6

Tags: python, vb6, i2c

I'm migrating a VB6 Code to Python which includes to create a ftd2xx.dll wrapper. I've used examples to create this.
The data for the write function of the DLL has to be a string. The problem that i have is, that for some characters Python and VB6 have different signs and because of that, it's writing wrong data to the Device. How do i get the same characters in Python like i get from chr() function in VB6?

VB6:

```
Private Sub AddToBuffer(AddWert As Long)
    OutIndex = OutIndex + 1             
    Mid(Out_Buffer, OutIndex, 1) = Chr(AddWert) 
End Sub
```

Python:

```
 def addToBuffer(self, AddWert):     
    self.outIndex += 1                  
    self.outBuffer = self.outBuffer + chr(AddWert)
    return None
```

Comment: *Some characters* isn't enough to go on. Could you explain which ones? It's almost certainly a string/ Unicode issue but it's hard to be specific with so little detail

Comment: The Characters which are wrong: 1 to 31, 127 to 159.
The numbers 1 to 31 return nothing and 127 to 159 return a question mark. I also think it's a unicode problem, but i couldn't find a fix with the unicodedata.normalize().

Comment: I voted this up because I think it is good, useful information that you are asking for. But I think the question as written could be made more clear (as already noted in other comments.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have VB6 so I can't guess what characters you are seeing there: you said what you are *getting* but not what you are *expecting*.

ASCII 0-31 are control characters: they are non-printing, in other words they don't have a glyph. For example, 13 is a carriage return and 10 is a linefeed.

Whatever glyph VB6 displays for those is nonstandard and you will probably have to translate them yourself. Hunt the glyphs down in a Unicode table and put them in a `dict`.

For the values 128 and above (which, whatever anybody tells you, are *undefined* in the ASCII standard) I am guessing (again) that VB6 would use Windows 1252, though perhaps not in your locale: you would know that better than I would.

This bit of code will covert the values that are part of the Windows 1252 mapping, which may be what you are looking for:

```
for i in range(32, 256):
    try:
        print (i, bytes([i]).decode("windows-1252"))
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        print (i, 'Not decodable')
```

This will give you what I think you are expecting except for 127 (which is also a control character) and 129, 141, 143, 144 and 157, which appear to have no mappings even in Windows 1252. If VB6 displays glyphs for them then the same remarks apply as for 0-31. As a side note, it might appear that 160 yields a blank or nothing: it doesn't. It's not easy to see, of course, but that is a non-breaking space.

So, for the characters above 31, instead of

```
self.outBuffer = self.outBuffer + chr(AddWert)
```

you can use

```
self.outBuffer = self.outBuffer + bytes([AddWert]).decode("windows-1252")
```